# Inserting an Element with a _parent field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm using ElasticSearch for an application in order to store and search for data.
Because it's also important to search for relationships in my particular case, I recently changed the structure of my data and I am using the _parent field now. (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html)

I already designed the search query, which works perfectly fine. However, I now have a problem when inserting a new child entry in my database.

It should work this way:

---

Without the _parent field, when I wanted to achieve this

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/data/child/1' -d '
```

I inserted the data this way using the JEST API:

```
client.execute(new Index.Builder(payload).index("data").type("child").build());
```

---

When I want to achieve this:

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/data/child?parent=154121-d'
```

How am I supposed to implement this using the JEST-API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible to provide a parameter for the request. The correct line of code to achieve this:

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/data/child?parent=154121-d'
```

would be achieved with this:

```
client.execute(new Index.Builder(payload).index("data").type("child").setParameter("parent", "154121").build());
```